# Numpy performance independent of vector length

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am having some trouble with the performance of numpy. It seems that performance of many operations is almost completely independent of vector length:

```
In [23]: y1 = np.random.randn(3)

In [24]: y2 = np.random.randn(300)

In [25]: %timeit np.mean(y1)
The slowest run took 9.65 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.91 µs per loop

In [26]: %timeit np.mean(y2)
The slowest run took 9.58 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.07 µs per loop

In [27]: %timeit np.median(y1)
The slowest run took 5.28 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.6 µs per loop

In [28]: %timeit np.median(y2)
The slowest run took 4.91 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.7 µs per loop

In [29]: %timeit np.max(y1)
The slowest run took 19.66 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 µs per loop

In [30]: %timeit np.max(y2)
The slowest run took 19.95 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.98 µs per loop
```

Is there something wrong with timeit?

Comment: I imagine that the issue is that both of those lists are very small and that the overhead comes from other places than simply finding the mean, median, and max. To see a difference try a BIG list

Comment: Numpy is incredibly efficient as it runs damn near natively. You would not see huge disparities over only a few hundred entries. Try creating one of 1,000, 10,000, 100,000, and 1,000,000 and maybe use PLT to plot the results to see the progression of time.

Comment: Compare those times with the equivalent calculations on lists, for example `sum(y1l)/len(y1l)` or `max(y1l)`.  Array operations have an overhead that obscures the per element variations at the small size.

Comment: @Goodies I could get that if it weren't that the overhead is so huge. 25.7us to find the median of a small list is very slow. I had expected ~1us runs for the large vector, and in the low nanosecond range for the small vector. Edit: ok, low ns is expecting a bit much, but a couple of 100 ns.